# How I decode eval wise Javascript

Tags: javascript, eval, decode

I want to use a template on my blogger blog site. But the template has js encoded by eval (wise)...
I don't know how to decode it...

Code Simple (Is not original code) :

```
eval(function(w,i,s,e){var lIll=0;var ll1I=0;var Il1l=0;var ll1l=[];var l1lI=[];while(true){if(lIll<5)l1lI.push(w.charAt(lIll));else if(lIll<w.length)ll1l.push(w.charAt(lIll));lIll++;if(ll1I<5)l1lI.push(i.charAt(ll1I));else if(ll1I<i.length)ll1l.push(i.charAt(ll1I));ll1I++;if(Il1l<5)l1lI.push(s.charAt(Il1l));else if(Il1l<s.length)ll1l.push(s.charAt(Il1l));Il1l++;if(w.length+i.length+s.length+e.length==ll1l.length+l1lI.length+e.length)break;}var lI1l=ll1l.join('');var I1lI=l1lI.join('');ll1I=0;var l1ll=[];for(lIll=0;lIll<ll1l.length;lIll+=2){var ll11=-1;if(I1lI.charCodeAt(ll1I)%2)ll11=1;l1ll.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(lI1l.substr(lIll,2),36)-ll11));ll1I++;if(ll1I>=l1lI.length)ll1I=0;}return l1ll.join('');}('','','','3cec1244c096c198fd3597fccab5ca32'));
```

My Question is, how to decode this type js?

Comment: Just run the function call that is passed as "argument" to `eval`?

Comment: "Is not original code" Please include the original code. The code you've provided doesn't work.

Comment: Orginal code is so much long... that's why I can't add here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, eval() is a function property of the global object.

The argument of the eval() function is a string. If the string represents an expression, eval() evaluates the expression. If the argument represents one or more JavaScript statements, eval() evaluates the statements. Do not call eval() to evaluate an arithmetic expression; JavaScript evaluates arithmetic expressions automatically.

in your code you can just remove eval and unminify your function using

http://unminify.com/

it will unminify your function. when I do I got this.

```
function(w, i, s, e) {
var lIll = 0;
var ll1I = 0;
var Il1l = 0;
var ll1l = [];
var l1lI = [];
while (true) {
    if (lIll < 5) l1lI.push(w.charAt(lIll));
    else if (lIll < w.length) ll1l.push(w.charAt(lIll));
    lIll++;
    if (ll1I < 5) l1lI.push(i.charAt(ll1I));
    else if (ll1I < i.length) ll1l.push(i.charAt(ll1I));
    ll1I++;
    if (Il1l < 5) l1lI.push(s.charAt(Il1l));
    else if (Il1l < s.length) ll1l.push(s.charAt(Il1l));
    Il1l++;
    if (w.length + i.length + s.length + e.length == ll1l.length + l1lI.length + e.length) break;
}
var lI1l = ll1l.join('');
var I1lI = l1lI.join('');
ll1I = 0;
var l1ll = [];
for (lIll = 0; lIll < ll1l.length; lIll += 2) {
    var ll11 = -1;
    if (I1lI.charCodeAt(ll1I) % 2) ll11 = 1;
    l1ll.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(lI1l.substr(lIll, 2), 36) - ll11));
    ll1I++;
    if (ll1I >= l1lI.length) ll1I = 0;
}
return l1ll.join('');
}('', '', '', '3cec1244c096c198fd3597fccab5ca32');
```

for more reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: *"Do not call eval() to evaluate an arithmetic expression; JavaScript evaluates arithmetic expressions automatically."* well, not if they the expression is inside a string. Otherwise this is a pretty arbitrary statement. *"If the string represents an expression, eval() evaluates the expression. If the argument represents one or more JavaScript statements, eval() evaluates the statements."* In other words, it evaluates JavaScript code inside the string.

Comment: same thing I mention in the first line.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the function into any javascript interpreter to see what is being passed into `eval`. You just need to replace `eval(...)` with `console.log(...)`

I did it here: https://repl.it/repls/LuminousChocolateMallard

It seems that the code generating the eval-ed code creates an infinite loop.

Comment: Yea, the code that generates the eval-ed code creates an infinite loop

Comment: My understanding is that the code has been obfuscated, and the function inside of eval generates the code OP wants to use. Am I misinterpreting OP?